# How do i configure Spatial mode in Hibernate search 6?

Tags: geospatial, hibernate-search, spatial-index, hibernate-search-6

I'm in the process of migrating from hibernate search 5 to 6. Many annotation classes that were present in hibernate search 5 have been completely removed in hibernate 6. One of these annotations was `@Spatial`. With this annotation you could configure which `SpatialMode` hibernate search should use when processing spatial information. For instance `SpatialMode.HASH`.

Now that `@Spatial` is gone, what is the proper way to set the spatial mode in hibernate 6?
I've already checked the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.1) but it doesn't mention anything about spatial modes.

EDIT: I believe [these are all the settings](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.1/api//org/hibernate/search/mapper/orm/cfg/HibernateOrmMapperSettings.html) hibernate search has.

EDIT 2: I did find this property `hibernate.search.backend.sharding.strategy` that can be set to hash. Is this the property that i need to set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [migration guide from Hibernate Search 5 to Hibernate Search 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/migration/html_single/)

In this guide, there is a [section about `@Spatial`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/migration/html_single/#spatial)

And in this section, there is a [subsection about `@Spatial.spatialMode`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/migration/html_single/#spatial-spatialmode):

> `@Spatial.spatialMode`, `@Spatial.topSpatialHashLevel`, `@Spatial.bottomSpatialHashLevel` have no equivalent in Hibernate Search 6: geohash-based geo-point fields are no longer supported.
>
> For Lucene, this is because Hibernate Search now uses Lucene’s built-in spatial support, which is range-based.
> For Elasticsearch, hash-based geo-point fields have never been available in the first place.